# Can I use google fonts in Google Drive web hosting?

Tags: html, google-drive-api

I was curious to try Google fonts in webpage that is hosted in public folder on Google Drive - but the fonts dont show up - is there a technique to use them in Google Drive or is it restricted?

Comment: I don't think you can any longer. Fonts might differ, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-hosted-css-not-working

Answer (score 7):

I found a technique to use Google Web fonts for myself by creating a secure link to Google's font apis - change the http to https like so:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

You should find this works!

Comment: Of course! This should be marked as the answer. Wonderful fix!

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason Google Drive web hosting doesn't like linking to external CSS.  Not sure how to fix it but I got around the problem by manually adding the google fonts css code to my css file.  For example:

Open the link from that HTML code they give you and you'll see some CSS code:

the HTML:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

The CSS that link leads to:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Francois One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Francois One Regular'), local('FrancoisOne-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/francoisone/v6/bYbkq2nU2TSx4SwFbz5sCHhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
}
```

If you copy that css code straight into your css file your fonts will display in a Google Drive hosted site.  If you don't have a separate css file you can just embed the css straight into your html code like so:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Francois One';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Francois One Regular'), local('FrancoisOne-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/francoisone/v6/bYbkq2nU2TSx4SwFbz5sCHhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Looks like it's a permissions issue that's blocking any external loading.  The fonts still don't work in internet explorer until you tell it to load everything.  In Chrome once you click the shield and tell it to load everything the fonts show up there too.  Hopefully this is something they can fix.