# Google Fonts and JQuery not working when hosted by Google Drive

Tags: hosting, google-drive-api

I've uploaded them to a public folder. Everything works apart from these two.

Is there some extra "Google Drive Hosting" script I need to put in?

Or should it be working without any extra and I need re-check my code?

Many thanks!

Comment: Don't worry. For anyone with the same problem I have found this answer... (It worked with the Google APIs JQuery link too)

  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15850891/2310591

Answer (score 0):

me also faced same problem while uploading my custom Jquery Plugin, bt i can able upload js file to an existing folder   which is already using for my previous project , me faced this problem while creating new folder only

but 
In my new folder me just deleted that  js file  and uploaded it again ,its working fr me nw

save file as .js
content of that file

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.doValidation = function(options) {
//ur code goes here 
}( jQuery ));
```